# Unable to run scheduled commands in Laravel until I clear cache

Tags: php, laravel, cron, laravel-scheduler

`php artisan schedule:run` gives me error after rebooting OS (Ubuntu).

```
No scheduled commands are ready to run
```

I can run this command many times and it does not start any commands.

BUT when I execute `php artisan cache:clear` all works as expected till next reboot.

What can be the reason?

.env has

```
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
```

Answer (score -4):

You can write this command in schedular like -:

```
Artisan::call('config:cache');
```

Comment: this will cause "withoutOverlapping" not to work